# Weigthening social media sentiment scores

Tags: r, sentiment-analysis

I struggle to understand how to implement a logical weighting of sentiment data.

I predicted the sentiment for multiple Reddit comments. How can I weight them according to their scores? The problem is sentiment data is going from -0.003 to 0.08 numerical, while scores can go from -1000 to 1000 (possible more). If you find any papers tackling this problem or could show me a viable direction, I would be thankful.

Objective: I try to weight the sentiment obtained from each comment in accordance to their score. I want that the score is reflected in the value to a degree which is good practice. In the end, my goal is to sum this weighted sentiment values to get a value which might be a representation of the sentiment at that day. What I struggle to find is papers or methods which are seen as good practice for score weighting. I obviously don't want to over use the scores, but It is not clear to me how much impact from the scores would make sense. There are multiple constraints from which a few I solved, e.g., negative scores should make the sentiment less impactful because a big majority of voters disagrees with the statement which I use e.g., a method like this for a/(2+cbe^{-kx}).

Minimal code example

```
 sentimentValues <- c(-0.0003, 0.0003, 0.025, -0.0001)

redditUserScores <- c(-5, 10, 1, 9)


date <- as.Date("2021/08/04")
len <- 3

datesRed <- c(date,seq(date, by = "day", length.out = len))

tib <- tibble(sentimentValues, redditUserScores, datesRed)


tib_cal <- tib %>% mutate(fit_calc = ifelse(redditUserScores >= 1,  redditUserScores * sentimentValues , sentimentValues)) 

  mean_df <- tib_cal %>% dplyr::group_by(datesRed) %>%  
    dplyr::summarise(fit = sum(fit_calc))
```

Comment: Is weightening the same as *weighting*? What problem is the weighting supposed to solve?

Comment: @Sycorax Hi, comments are upvoted and downvoted, which signal agreement or disagreement with a comment. I get a sentiment for each comment and would like to make comments more impactful with many upvotes and comments less impactful with many downvotes.

Comment: @Elias impactful on what? What is the problem or question you want to solve ultimately? (e.g. do you want to calculate an average sentiment score? Or are you looking for something else?). I repeat the question Sycorax asked, because weighting might not be the right tool to use here, depending on the question you want to answer. (Welcome on CrossValidated by the way!)

Comment: There are so many possible ways to create weights that give more weight to comments with upvotes and less weight to comments with downvotes that there are far too many possible answers for this to be useful. A suitable version of this question would outline how the weighting will be used and what properties of the weighting are desirable and undesirable.